# Cature video in IOS application and add some more buttons with default button in the default cature mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing one IOS app. In this I need to capture video. I know default to capture video from app like below screen but here I want to capture video customly, that is need to remove the bar which contains the button **CANCEL** and **RECORD** instead of this button I want to add RECORD and CANCEL customly, because I need to add some more controls with those button.

Any suggestions, I will appreciate greatly..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your custom view with your own controls to `cameraOverlayView` property of your `UIImagePickerController` and set `showsCameraControls` to `NO`.